# Lightning Web Component Datatable - enabling editing on a cell by cell basis rather than by column

Tags: lightning-web-components

I've been looking at the LWC `lightning-datatable` component and its inline editing feature. I have a working version up and running, but have run into a limitation and am looking for a workaround.

The editability of each of the table cells is determined by the config that is passed to the `columns` property of the component. Each column definition has an `editable` property:

```
// Template
<lightning-datatable
    ...
    columns={columnsDefinition}>
</lightning-datatable>

// Component Class
...
@track columnsDefinition = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', editable: true },
    ...
];
```

While this is great if all of the cells for a column have the same editability rules, I would like to switch editability on and off on a cell by cell basis:

*e.g. if the value in this cell is greater than 100,000 then it can be edited, if not it can't be.*

Is there any way to achieve this?

From the docs it doesn't look like there is with the pre-built component. I think the only option might be to build a totally custom solution using the Lightning Design System styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was `cellAttributes` or `typeAttributes`, its possible to refer to other field values but when its direct column attribute like `editable`, you cannot do it. It just applies to whole column.

For example, in below column, `iconname` will be referred to `trendIcon` column. This is not possible for `editable`.

```
{label: 'Confidence', fieldName: 'confidence', type: 'percent', cellAttributes:
   { iconName: { fieldName: 'trendIcon' }, iconPosition: 'right' }},
```

Comment: Also: trying to use the typeattribute disabled won't work either.